# Get Last Arrays Item in Several Nested Fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a dynamic nested fields like `user.com1.grp1.history` which `history` is a set of hash tables.

Sample structure:

```
{
    _id: "123456",
    user: {
        com1: {
            grp1: {
                history: [
                    {
                         action: "something",
                         ...
                    }
                    ...
                ]
            },
            grp2: {
                history: [
                    {
                        action: "something else"
                        ...
                    }
                    ...
                ]
            },
         },
        com2: {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to get last item of `history` for `grp`s, this way works fine:

```
db.user.find({}, {user.com1.grp1.history: {$slice: -1}})
```

But the problem is here that `com`s and `grp`s are dynamic names and each `user` contains many dynamic `com`s and each `com` contains many dynamic `grp`s and I can't call query for each of them.

So how can I get last items of each `com/grp`'s `history` in this situation?